# How to sort ABAddressBook contact through First Name

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, abaddressbook

I have a sort function that sorts the Address book by Last Name, I need to modify this code so that it will sort by first Name. Where do I need to make change in this code. I know its a simple change but I am unable to figure it out. This is the code that sorts the contacts list by Last Name

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFMutableArrayRef peopleMutable = CFArrayCreateMutableCopy
                                       (
                                          kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                          CFArrayGetCount(people),
                                          people
                                       );


CFArraySortValues
       (
        peopleMutable,
        CFRangeMake(0, CFArrayGetCount(peopleMutable)),
        (CFComparatorFunction) ABPersonComparePeopleByName,
        (void*) ABPersonGetSortOrdering()
       );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implement your sort method by bellow put `kABPersonSortByFirstName` instead of  `(void*) ABPersonGetSortOrdering()`:-

```
CFArraySortValues(peopleMutable,
                  CFRangeMake(0, CFArrayGetCount(peopleMutable)),
                  (CFComparatorFunction) ABPersonComparePeopleByName,
                  kABPersonSortByFirstName);
```

Credit goes to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976555/address-book-contact-sorting)

Comment: Thanks that seems to work, I wonder why didnt I find that page when I searched for it in stack overflow before and also I did tried that with kABPersonSortByLastName and it showed error so I didnt bother trying the other one:P

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
    addressBookArray = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByLastName);
```

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to sort them and if you want to work with the same code check Nitin's answer:-

```
        ABRecordRef person = (__bridge ABRecordRef)record;

        NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

        if ( [beginsPredicate evaluateWithObject:firstName] )
        {
            ABRecordID abRecordID = ABRecordGetRecordID(person);

            [self.filteredPeople addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:abRecordID]];
        }
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 //Sorting

 ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
            ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
            NSArray *allPeople = (__bridge NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName);
```